# Xamarin Forms GridView Does Not Put Image On Second Row

Tags: gridview, xamarin.forms, android-gridview

I am trying to have two buttons side by side at the top of the grid, and an image below them that spans across both columns. But the image keeps staying at the top on the side of the two buttons and won't go down to the next row.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Rowdefinition>
        <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.Rowdefinition>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinition>

    <telerikInput:RadButton x:Name="signin" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"        Text="Sign In" BackgroundColor="#2F7DC0" TextColor="white" BorderRadius="0"/>
    <telerikInput:RadButton x:Name="signup" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Sign Up" BackgroundColor="#2F7DC0" TextColor="white" BorderRadius="0" />
    <Image Source="https://xamarin.com/content/images/pages/forms/example-app.png" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

</Grid>
```

Comment: You're missing closing tag for `</Grid>` - assuming that's just a copy/paste issue. Try setting `Aspect=AspectFill` on the `ImageSource`. Also, what version of Xamarin.Forms you're using?

Comment: Can you please change the Width property of RowDefinition to Height?
<RowDefinition Height="*"/>